# What's the point of WebMatrix?

Tags: webmatrix

I'm not trying to be mean or imply that there isn't a point.  I'm just wondering what the point of WebMatrix is, exactly?

I see that it is trying to lower the barriers to entry to programming MS stuff...but it doesn't seem like anyone building a reasonable website would be able to do so without VS using this app.

I'm a developer who has done .NET exclusively for several years, so perhaps the issue is that I'm not the intended audience...?

Comment: That's exactly the issue. You are not the intended audience. It's audience is beginners before college; hobbyists; etc.

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft the [point of WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/features.aspx) is:

> WebMatrix was built to streamline Web development and make it easy, whether you're getting started or you just want to get things done. It lets you focus on what’s important — your Web site.

From my point of view this is targeted to someone who has a grasp of HTML and CSS and it looking for an entry point into developing web applications without needing to learn how to set up the technologies that support the application itself like databases or webservers.